# Stackplot "TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types"

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, typeerror

Trying to stackplot two arrays with the following code. I've tried to strip down the problem to figure out the cause but problem persists.

```
diet_projection = perc_contributions_WRAP.percentage_contributions(diet_props, 2050, 1961, 2013)

print(diet_projection.iloc[:].values)
print(np.arange(2013, 2051, 1))

plt.stackplot(np.arange(2013, 2051, 1), diet_projection.iloc[:].values)
# plt.legend(loc = "upper left")
# plt.ylabel("Diet makeup - kcal/capita/day")
# plt.xlabel("Year")
# plt.xticks(np.arange(2010, 2050, 5))
plt.show()
```

This returns the following:

```
[[0.7772766317126378 0.7760459815112983 0.7748153313099588
  0.7735846811086193 0.7723540309072798 0.7711233807059403
  0.7698927305046008 0.7686620803032613 0.7674314301019218
  0.7662007799005823 0.7649701296992428 0.7637394794979033
  0.7625088292965638 0.7612781790952243 0.7600475288938848
  0.7588168786925453 0.7575862284912058 0.7563555782898663
  0.7551249280885268 0.7538942778871873 0.7526636276858478
  0.7514329774845083 0.7502023272831688 0.7489716770818293
  0.7477410268804898 0.7465103766791503 0.7452797264778108
  0.7440490762764713 0.7428184260751318 0.7415877758737923
  0.7403571256724528 0.7391264754711133 0.7378958252697738
  0.7366651750684343 0.7354345248670948 0.7342038746657553
  0.7329732244644158 0.7317425742630763]
 [0.21688670893743733 0.21809486726005778 0.21930302558267778
  0.22051118390529822 0.22171934222791823 0.22292750055053867
  0.22413565887315912 0.22534381719577912 0.22655197551839956
  0.22776013384101956 0.22896829216364 0.23017645048626
  0.23138460880888045 0.2325927671315009 0.2338009254541209
  0.23500908377674135 0.23621724209936135 0.2374254004219818
  0.2386335587446018 0.23984171706722224 0.24104987538984224
  0.24225803371246268 0.24346619203508313 0.24467435035770313
  0.24588250868032357 0.24709066700294358 0.24829882532556402
  0.24950698364818402 0.25071514197080447 0.2519233002934249
  0.2531314586160449 0.25433961693866536 0.25554777526128536
  0.2567559335839058 0.2579640919065258 0.25917225022914625
  0.2603804085517667 0.2615885668743867]
 [0.005836659349924521 0.0058591512286437705 0.00588164310736302
  0.005904134986082277 0.005926626864801526 0.005949118743520783
  0.0059716106222400325 0.005994102500959282 0.006016594379678539
  0.006039086258397788 0.006061578137117045 0.0060840700158362945
  0.006106561894555551 0.006129053773274801 0.00615154565199405
  0.006174037530713307 0.0061965294094325565 0.006219021288151813
  0.006241513166871063 0.006264005045590312 0.006286496924309569
  0.0063089888030288185 0.006331480681748075 0.006353972560467325
  0.006376464439186574 0.006398956317905831 0.0064214481966250805
  0.006443940075344337 0.006466431954063587 0.006488923832782843
  0.006511415711502093 0.0065339075902213425 0.006556399468940599
  0.006578891347659849 0.006601383226379105 0.006623875105098355
  0.0066463669838176045 0.006668858862536861]]
[2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020 2021 2022 2023 2024 2025 2026
 2027 2028 2029 2030 2031 2032 2033 2034 2035 2036 2037 2038 2039 2040
 2041 2042 2043 2044 2045 2046 2047 2048 2049 2050]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_sort.py", line 130, in <module>
    analysis_temp()
  File "data_sort.py", line 129, in analysis_temp
    SA()
  File "data_sort.py", line 122, in SA
    plt.stackplot(np.arange(2013, 2051, 1), diet_projection.iloc[:].values)
  File "C:\Users\Thomas Ball\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2915, in stackplot
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Thomas Ball\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1810, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Thomas Ball\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 4858, in stackplot
    return mstack.stackplot(self, x, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Thomas Ball\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\stackplot.py", line 110, in stackplot
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Thomas Ball\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1810, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Thomas Ball\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5049, in fill_between
    y2 = ma.masked_invalid(self.convert_yunits(y2))
  File "C:\Users\Thomas Ball\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\ma\core.py", line 2366, in masked_invalid
    condition = ~(np.isfinite(a))
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I can't see what could be causing the error. All the numbers are within a normal range etc.

I've tried without the .values but that also returns the same error (this normally works just fine with .stackplot).

Comment: Can you create a [mcve], i.e. a self-contained piece of code that when copied,pasted and run reproduces the problem?

Comment: So I copied the data from the output to try to replicate the error, doing `data = [copied data]` and `plt.stackplot(np.arange(2013, 2051, 1), data)` and that worked. Also `df.plot.area()` works on the original code. Just not sure what the problem is with stackplot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding `.astype(float)` to the line `diet_projection = perc_contributions_WRAP.percentage_contributions(diet_props, 2050, 1961, 2013)`, which is where the data is generated from originally. Not quite sure how it lost the float or int64 type in the first place, however.